# associating Google Maps Business API key with geocoder searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-geocoding-api, rails-geocoder

I have a background rails job using geocoder for records that have a latitude and a longitude. I also have a license for the Google Maps API v3. This (obviously) won't be hitting the javascript API.

According to the docs listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/):

```
User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.
```

However, according the API docs, you do **not** to include the api key in your request URLs.

Does anyone know I can ensure that my usage of the geocoder api via the rails geocoder gem can be associated with my account? I'd prefer not to hit the limit.

Answer (score -4):

You need to include a client parameter which is your client-id and you need to sign your requests. You can find out more information in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices

Comment: But does this place nicely with ruby geocoder? And is the the Map Business API distinct from the Google Premier API? It seems to talk about them interchangeably.

Comment: And actually - if you have any more knowledge about this it would be greatly appreciated, but it looks like google has several different products? 1) Google Maps API V3, 2) Google Maps Business API for business, 3) something called either Premiere API or Enterpris? Or is that the same as #2? The documentation on their product offering is unclear and self-contradicting.

Comment: I don't know ruby at all, or the geocoder gem. It should be fairly easy to construct a web service request. Maps API for Business is the new name for Maps API Premier. Enterprise license is just another way to refer to the same thing.